# How can windows admin run a process as a normal user without providing password of the user?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, runas

I have following situation ..

Bob is a windows admin.
John is a normal user.

Bob wants to run a process with John's user id.

I can use runas , but it is prompting for password of John. 
Is there another way i can run the process without providing John's password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not run a process as another user without knowing that user's password, even if you use service accounts, you still need to know the passwords to run applications/process/services and etc. as that user.

Comment: I am looking for something like "sudo -u". Is there no way of doing that?

Comment: is that Linux command? not familiar with that one.

Comment: This is factually wrong, the function LsaLogonUser as well as the undocumented ZwCreateToken allows getting a token without knowing the password. How else would e.g. the task scheduler allow you to create tasks where you can choose not to save the password?